# Python print function does not print in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to print the variables (which i take with the beautiful soup) in order with 'for in' in python. 
I have two variables, 'name' and 'price'. I want to print name first, price second for all of the products.

> Problem: The price is always printed first. And deletes characters from name.

```
for product in soup.find_all('div',class_='class'):
    name = product.contents[3].text
    price = product.contents[5].text
    print(name, price, sep=' ')
```

i also tried

```
print(name, price)
```

if name="aaa bbb ccc" and price="12345 Dollars" output is

```
12345 Dollarsbbb ccc
```

i expect output to be in order and don't delete characters.

Comment: There's probably a carriage return (`"\r"`) at the end of `name` or the beginning of `price`.

Comment: can you share url as may be another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your name probably has a carriage return character at the end (`'\r'`)

try

```
print(name.strip(), price.strip())
```

Comment: @JohnColeman How so? If their python interpreter isn't broken, which I don't believe, that's the only viable explanation

Comment: @JohnColeman It's a very good guess. I give it a 99% chance of being right.

Comment: @JohnColeman I could add an explanation on why a carriage return will cause the observed effect, if you'd like me to